# C Program - How to initialize a Long Size Array

Tags: c, arrays, memset

I have a programs like this,

**Program 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 0x320204

int main ()
{
    unsigned long long_array[ARRAY_SIZE];

    memset (long_array, 0, ARRAY_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

**Program 2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 0x320204

int main ()
{
    unsigned long long_array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};

    //memset (long_array, 0, ARRAY_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

Both Programs are giving Segmentation Fault.

Please clarify how to initialize this long size array. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The code probably hits the stack's size limit when trying to allocate this "huge" array.

Comment: This "*`memset (long_array, 0, ARRAY_SIZE);`*" most likely wouldn't do what you might expect (but few).

Comment: The very similar question was here like 10 minutes ago...

Comment: the number 0x320204 is equal to 3277316,which is bigger than the stack size.

Comment: Aside from `ARRAY_SIZE` being a large number, code should have been `memset(long_array, 0, sizeof *long_array * ARRAY_SIZE);` or even better `memset(long_array, 0, sizeof long_array);`

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c

Answer (score 4):

The segmentation fault is because you try to allocate on the stack `0x320204` `long`s, which may be too much. In decimal, this is `3277316 * sizeof(unsigned long)`, which on my machine is `3277316 * 8 = 26218528` bytes, i.e. around 25 Mbytes.

The second way of initializing it is the most common, it will zero all elements. The first method will only zero the first `ARRAY_SIZE` bytes, but remember that `sizeof(unsigned long)` is usually `8` bytes, so you need to zero `sizeof(unsigned long) * ARRAY_SIZE` bytes.

Comment: Rather than "need to zero `8 * ARRAY_SIZE` bytes", suggest "need to zero `sizeof (unsigned long long) * ARRAY_SIZE` bytes" or "need to zero `sizeof long_array` bytes".  Thus avoiding magic numbers like 8.

Comment: Edited, OP is using `long` (not `long long`)

Comment: @AlterMann thanks, my mistake, when I skimmed through the code there were 2 adjacent `long`'s, and didn't realize that the last was part of a name :)

Comment: @Alter Mann Your comment is a fine example of why to use `sizeof var` rather than `sizeof(type)`.

Comment: @chux I guess the best is to use `ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof *array_name`, no more issues whatsoever even if you decide later to change the type.

Comment: IMO `sizeof array_name` is best. YMMV.

Comment: @chux Yeah, if it's an array, indeed. The only issue is with dynamic allocated ones, but technically those are not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use [`calloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html), which is only one call, clearer to a lot of people, though not really a big deal, and uses the heap, which is the biggest benefit. Once you want to make really big array (or objects, or whatever), the heap is the place for you. Eventually, using the stack for this kind of stuff isn't practical, and will likely cause a stackoverflow error. Plus, you can pass this pointer returned from `calloc` to anything with having to worry what will happen to that memory allocated. This is unlike the stack, where it will probably be overwritten once that function returns, something that has happened to me plenty of times, creating bugs that are super hard to fix. There are downsides, however, to `calloc` like the fact that its pretty slow, but just as fast as `memset`in this case. But if you don't really NEED all the bits to be set to 0, you could use [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) (much faster and more popular). The second downside to `calloc` or `malloc` is that you must call [`free`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) on the pointers, otherwise you leak memory. Here's how to use `calloc`:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // or "#include <cstdlib>" in C++


/* Allocate space for array, set all bytes to 0,
   and return pointer. Then assign to long_array.
*/
unsigned long* long_array = (unsigned long*) calloc(ARRAY_SIZE);
// When you're done with this variable:
free(long_array);
```

Easy as that. Both `calloc` and `malloc` are made for this kind of stuff. I hope this helped!

Note: Though these links are to a C++ website, you can still use these functions in pure C by including `<stdlib.h>`